# Why is Update-Package -reinstall ( Nuget ) never completing?

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I started running from within Visual Studio 2012

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

because I had accidently removed files from the packages directory.

Nuget is still working 10 minutes later as I type. I expected it perhaps to take a bit to download all the packages in one go and then quickly whip through linking all the projects up to the packages.

However it seems to take between 1 and two seconds per nuget sub operation and there are hundreds of operations Is this normal?

The log output looks like

```
Successfully added 'Rx-Core 2.1.30214.0' to Numerics.Spec.
Adding 'Rx-Linq 2.1.30214.0' to Numerics.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-Linq 2.1.30214.0' to Numerics.Spec.
Adding 'Rx-PlatformServices 2.1.30214.0' to Numerics.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-PlatformServices 2.1.30214.0' to Numerics.Spec.
Adding 'Rx-Main 2.1.30214.0' to Numerics.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-Main 2.1.30214.0' to Numerics.Spec.
Adding 'reactiveui-core 5.1.2' to Numerics.Spec.
Successfully added 'reactiveui-core 5.1.2' to Numerics.Spec.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Main (≥ 2.1.30214.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Interfaces (≥ 2.1.30214.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Core (≥ 2.1.30214.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-Linq (≥ 2.1.30214.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Rx-PlatformServices (≥ 2.1.30214.0)'.
'reactiveui-core 5.1.2' already installed.
Adding 'Rx-Interfaces 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-Interfaces 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Adding 'Rx-Core 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-Core 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Adding 'Rx-Linq 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-Linq 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Adding 'Rx-PlatformServices 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-PlatformServices 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Adding 'Rx-Main 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Successfully added 'Rx-Main 2.1.30214.0' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Adding 'reactiveui-core 5.1.2' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
Successfully added 'reactiveui-core 5.1.2' to Weingartner.Controls.Spec.
```

and is being continually updated so it has not frozen just real real slow.

It is repeating itself over and over again. A grep through the log in vim gives

[image]

I also see errors in the log

```
Failed to generate binding redirects for 'EyeShotExtensions'. An item with the same key has already been added.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a work item for improving the performance Update-Package -reinstall. Please stayed tuned for our future releases. Thanks.